# To obtain individual list values in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

How to obtain the individual value of the list item in `${jobs.value}`
to apply i18n labels which is a string value for each items in `${jobs.value}`

The code below displays all item `items in ${jobs.value}`, we need individual item to display and in string type

```
    <c:forEach var="job" items="${jobs.value}">
       <p>${job}</p>          
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `<p>${job}</p>` to `<p><c:out value="${job}"/></p>`.

Comment: Tried it is displaying all the values like                                                                red                                                                                                                    green                                                                                                                yellow                                                                                                           How to apply i18n values if it likes a list

Comment: We are using 18n.getProperties("xyz") for obtaining the values for i18n

Comment: What is `18n.getProperties("xyz")`? I cannot answer if you are using a non-standard technology.

Comment: My query is I need to implement i18n for the ${jobs.value} in jsp

Comment: You can use JSTL `fmt` that is an i18n-capable formatting library. For example, `<fmt:message key="property.key" />`.